# Only loop through posts that have filled custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type "Team" with multiple custom fields. I want to make a shortcode that displays the value of the field "team_foto_met_koptelefoon" when the post has as image set for that custom field.

On every pageload, another image from a different person is loaded, but when the person has no image, it shows nothing.

I tried writing a query to loop through all the posts, but it also loops through the teammembers who don't have the image set.

```
function dfib_team_spotify_shortcode( $atts ) {
    ob_start();
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'team',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'rand',
    ) );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
            <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                <?php if( get_field('team_foto_met_koptelefoon') ): ?>
                    <img class="team__spotify__img" src="<?php the_field('team_foto_met_koptelefoon'); ?>">
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <?php $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
    return $myvariable;
    }
}

add_shortcode( 'team__spotify', 'dfib_team_spotify_shortcode' );
```

I want to make a loop that checks which team member has as image set in "team_foto_met_koptelefoon" and only display the members that have an image so I don't end up with empty spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution myself by adding a couple extra lines:

```
<?php
function dfib_team_spotify_shortcode( $atts ) {
    ob_start();

    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'         => 'team',
        'posts_per_page'    => 1,
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'meta_key'          => 'team_foto_met_koptelefoon', //ACF field name
        'meta_value'        => ' ',
        'meta_compare'      => '!=',
        'orderby'           => 'rand',
    ) );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            <?php if( get_field('team_foto_met_koptelefoon') ): ?>
                <img class="team__spotify__img" src="<?php the_field('team_foto_met_koptelefoon'); ?>">
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endwhile;

        wp_reset_postdata();

        $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
        return $myvariable;
     }
}
add_shortcode( 'team__spotify', 'dfib_team_spotify_shortcode' );
?>
```